# Cannot find div with id when within nested anonymous function

Tags: ajax, jquery, partial-views

I have an ajax call within another anonymous function. The problem I am having is that the length of this is zero.

```
//data_ajax_target equals '#partial_f_Picture'
Debug.Log($(data_ajax_target).length); // equal zero.
```

This prevents the html returned from the ajax call from replacing the contents of the div.

Here is my div

```
<div id="#partial_f_Picture">
    <div id="fileuploader-small-f_Picture" 
        data-ajax-uploadurl="...omitted..."
        data-ajax-target="#partial_f_Picture">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my reduced javascript

```
$(function ()
{
    FileUploaderSmallReady();
});
```

...

```
function FileUploaderSmallReady()
{
    var uploaderDiv = $('[id^="fileuploader-small"]').each(function ()
    {
        var data_ajax_uploadurl = $(this).attr('data-ajax-uploadurl');
        var data_ajax_target = $(this).attr('data-ajax-target');

        var uploadersmall = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')),
            action: data_ajax_uploadurl,
            onComplete: function (file, response, responseJSON)
            {
                var data_ajax_url = responseJSON['data_ajax_url'];
                if (typeof data_ajax_url != 'undefined')
                {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "GET",
                            url: data_ajax_url,
                            beforeSend: AjaxBegin(),
                            success: function (html)
                            {
                                Debug.Log(data_ajax_target);
                                //== #partial_f_Picture

                                Debug.Log($(data_ajax_target).length);
                                //== 0
                                $(data_ajax_target).html(html);
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        });});} //moved braces up to prevent code from being in a scroll window.
```

Comment: you know instead of doing `$('selector').attr('data-whatever')` you can do `$('selector').data('whatever')` right?

Comment: what happens when you hard code the string value in, `$('#partial_f_Picture').length`, do you get a value?

Comment: Length is still zero. I will look into that data suggestion, thanks.

Comment: so it seems like you've left out some important information

Comment: @Jason, I prefer to stick with `.attr()` when I want to read an element attribute because I don't like the way `.data()` does automatic type conversion. (I only use `.data()` to retrieve values that were stored with `.data()`.)

Comment: i suppose that's fair, but you're just retrieving a string here ;)

Comment: @Jason - yep, the OP (not me) is just retrieving a string so `.data()` will work fine here. For my own code I just figure that if I get in the habit of using `.data()` for attributes that are strings I'll eventually confuse myself during some hypothetical future debugging session on code that uses attributes that contain numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<div id="#partial_f_Picture">` to `<div id="partial_f_Picture">`.  The `#` in the selector means "it's an id" (as opposed to `.` which means "it's a class" and lack-of-prefix which means "it's a dom tag" (`p`, `div`, etc)).